# How to set image for android object

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm having trouble trying to add an image inside the object

This is my Category entity

```
@PrimaryKey
private int categoryId;

@ColumnInfo
private String categoryName;

@ColumnInfo
private String categoryImage;
```

and then I tried adding image by this

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "foodOrder").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        Category category = new Category
(2, "Drink", "D:\\SourceCode\\Android\\PRM\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable-xxxhdpi\\pizza.jpg");
        db.categoryService().insertAll(category);
```

but it didn't show the image. So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have coded a path (*D:\SourceCode\Android\PRM\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\pizza.jpg*) that is on the computer that you are developing the App on. Your computer is not available to the device/emulator at run time.

You need to save the resource name and use that to retrieve the resource.

Perhaps refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources